# Getting an error while running truffle init command

Tags: macos, blockchain, ethereum, truffle

I've installed `truffle` successfully but when I run `truffle init` I always get the following error:

`Downloading...
Error: read ETIMEDOUT
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:111:27)`

Node, npm and system version:

```
node -v
  v10.10.0

npm -v
  6.4.1

truffle version
  Truffle v4.1.14 (core: 4.1.14)
  Solidity v0.4.24 (solc-js)

ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.13.6
```

Any ideas how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution I came up is to downgrade `node` to `v8.12.0` and it works.